# Rotate p paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate paragraphs, however they get not enough space and mix up. How to separate them?

The last child must not be visible, hence display none. Also there must be no space between them. So basically it should be like

```
Hello.Move.Explore.Bla.
```

And then 90 degrees turned. However this is what I get:

[image: Unwanted rotate effect]

I tried the div with flexbox column, however it produces space between the p-tags.

```css
p {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

p:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform90">
    <p>Hello.</p>
    <p>Move.</p>
    <p>Explore.</p>
    <p>Bla.</p>
    <p>Longword.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some padding `p { padding: 10px; }`

Comment: @SarwarAhmed Nope still mixes up the last 2 words then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead off `rotate`, use [`writing-mode: vertical-rl;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode):

> [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)
>
> The writing-mode CSS property sets whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically ...
>
> ---
>
> [`vertical-rl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#values)
>
> For ltr scripts, content flows vertically from top to bottom, and the next vertical line is positioned to the left of the previous line. For rtl scripts, content flows vertically from bottom to top, and the next vertical line is positioned to the right of the previous line.

```css
p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

p:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Hello.</p>
    <p>Move.</p>
    <p>Explore.</p>
    <p>Bla.</p>
    <p>Longword.</p>
</div>
```

---

For browser compatibility please see [this diagram](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#browser_compatibility) or [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=vertical-rl).

Comment: tb-rl .. https://caniuse.com/?search=writing-mode This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used... so how browser compatible is this.

Comment: Thx @Jack70, I've changed my answer to use the more up-to-date `vertical-rl`

Comment: Thanks @0stone0, yea just found that too, and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this, makes more sense:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        p>span:last-child {
           display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="transform90">
    <p><span>Hello.</span><span>Move.</span><span>Explore.</span><span>Bla.</span><span>Longword.</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comes out of a CMS.. too much work to rebuild the editor and explain the people just to produce the spans.